# Domain issues with WWW

Tags: domain, domain-name, www

I have this domain that I recently brought:

But if I access to:

It shows the website where I brought the domain from, why is it doing this?

Comment: I don't see the problem... both sites bring up the same for me...

Comment: What he said.  Looks fine to me.  Clear your cache?

Comment: Hmm... the DNS probably hasn't settled yet.

Comment: DNS propagates slowly, it may have reached some DNS servers but not others, this process can take a few days to propagate entirely, be patient.

Comment: I am patience, but I was just wondering about the domain without the WWW is already propagated but not with the WWW, how can it have the effect?

Comment: I see both URLs too.

Comment: When the domain was first set up, it could have been done with just one of the A records, and the second might have been added in a later stage of the setup process, and thus delayed.

Comment: @MaQleod, could you post an answer so I can choose an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS propagates slowly, it may have reached some DNS servers but not others, this process can take a few days to propagate entirely, be patient.

When the domain was first set up, it could have been done with just one of the A records, and the second might have been added in a later stage of the setup process, and thus delayed.